# RMLStreamer Function grel:array_join produces inconsistent results

Tags: rdf, rml-rdf

In RMLStreamer, grel:arra_join function does not produce the expected results.

Mapping File (mapping.ttl)

```
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix grel:     <http://users.ugent.be/~bjdmeest/function/grel.ttl#> .
@prefix idlab-fn: <http://example.com/idlab/function/> .
@prefix fno:      <https://w3id.org/function/ontology#> .
@prefix gist: <http://ontologies.semanticarts.com/gist#>.
@prefix fnml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/fnml#> .
@base <http://example.com/base/> .

<TriplesMap1> a rr:TriplesMap;
              rml:logicalSource [
                                    rml:source "student.csv";
                                    rml:referenceFormulation ql:CSV
                                ];
              rr:subjectMap [
                                rr:template "http://example.com/{ID}/{Name}";
                                rr:class foaf:Person
                            ];
              rr:predicateObjectMap [
                                        rr:predicate ex:id ;
                                        rr:objectMap [ rml:reference "ID" ]
                                    ];
              rr:predicateObjectMap [
                                        rr:predicate gist:end;
                                        rr:objectMap <#FunctionMapDateTimeEnd>
                                    ].

<#FunctionMapDateTimeEnd> a fnml:FunctionTermMap;
                          rr:datatype  xsd:dateTime;
                          fnml:functionValue [
                                         rml:logicalSource "student.csv";
                                         rr:predicateObjectMap [
                                                 rr:predicate fno:executes;
                                                 rr:objectMap [ rr:constant grel:array_join ] ;
                                                               ] ;
                                         rr:predicateObjectMap [
                                                 rr:predicate grel:p_array_a ;
                                                 rr:objectMap [ rml:reference "date" ] ;
                                                                ] ;
                                         rr:predicateObjectMap [
                                                rr:predicate grel:p_array_a ;
                                                rr:objectMap [ rr:constant "T12:00:00.000Z"; ] ;
                                                               ] ;
                                             ].
```

student.csv

```
ID,Name,Comment,Class,date
1,Venus,A&B,A,2019-11-01
```

Output

```
<http://example.com/1/Venus> <http://ontologies.semanticarts.com/gist#end> "T12:00:00.000Z2019-11-01"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> .
<http://example.com/1/Venus> <http://example.com/id> "1" .
<http://example.com/1/Venus> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
```

The problem with the output is the order of join by grel:array_join. Executing the same files multiple times generate different results.

```
<http://example.com/1/Venus> <http://ontologies.semanticarts.com/gist#end> "T12:00:00.000Z2019-11-01"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> .
```

```
<http://example.com/1/Venus> <http://ontologies.semanticarts.com/gist#end> "2019-11-01T12:00:00.000Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> .
```

However, the expected output is to join the list in the given order (2019-11-01T12:00:00.000Z) every time.

The same mapping file with RMLMapper produces consistent and correct results and join the list in the given order.

Other functions such as grel:toUpperCase and idlab-fn:toUpperCaseURL work fine and produce correct results in both RMLStreamer and RMLMapper

Answer (score 0):

To solve your specific issue, have you tried replacing `<#FunctionMapDateTimeEnd>` with a template-valued term map with template `"{date}T12:00:00.000Z"`? Alternatively, you could [link your own function](https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java/#including-functions) to concatenate two strings. If that function uses named parameters, their order is preserved by default.

More generally, there are indeed some known issues with preserving order in RML+FnO array parameters, although there is also work to fix them, see for example [this issue](https://github.com/RMLio/yarrrml-parser/issues/78) and the [related community group page](https://github.com/kg-construct/rml-fno-spec).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a solution to fix this particular case `[rr:template "{date}T12:00:00.000Z"; rr:termType rr:Literal;];`  However, the main problem I am facing is to read URL from data as a base of `rr:subjectMap` IRI. SubjectMap doesn't allow `rr:template "{url}"`. One of solutions I found suggested to use array_join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900785/is-there-any-way-in-rml-r2rml-to-take-a-value-as-an-iri PS: In your answer link of [this issue] doesn't work.